# Trouble including properties in generic entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Consider having QuotationForm, OrderForm, and DeliveryForm deriving from FormableEntity which is an abstract class.
In the QuotationForm, I have a collection (ICollection) of QuotationLine and other fields.

```
    public class QuotationEntity : FormableEntity, ISummable
{
    double DiscountPercent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<QuotationLineEntity> Lines { get; set; } = new List<QuotationLineEntity>();
    public double Total
    {
        get
        {
            double PercentOfTotal = 1.0 - (DiscountPercent / 100.0);
            return Lines.Aggregate(0.0, (sum, line) => sum + line.Total) * PercentOfTotal;
        }
    }
}

public class QuotationLineEntity : ISummable, IEntityBase
{
    int LineNumber { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    string DeliveryTime { get; set; }
    string Notes { get; set; }
    Guid ReferencingLine { get; set; }
    string ReferencingMainAppId { get; set; }
    public double Total
    {
        get
        {
            return UnitPrice * Quantity;
        }
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DbContext, so far with this:

```
public DbSet<FormableEntity> Forms { get; set; }
public DbSet<QuotationLineEntity> QuotationLines { get; set; }
```

Now, in the Repository, I'm trying to get a form based on its Type `T` and Id:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(Guid id) where T : class, IEntityBase { WHAT SHOULD BE HERE? }
```

I was trying to check for the type and include the needed containers, like this:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(QuotationEntity)){
    var set = m_context.Set<QuotationEntity>.Where(f => f.Id == id);
}
```

but then, the `.Include` does not work.
Also, I'm trying to be generic, so consider having OrderLines and DeliveryLines inside a OrderForm and DeliveryForm, and a base class for all the Line entities (including the QuotationLine), which means, that `public DbSet<QuotationLineEntity> QuotationLines { get; set; }` will change to `public DbSet<FormLineEntity> FormLines { get; set; }`. I find it impossible to achieve what is needed, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your collections virtual. For further reading use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Just to be sure, the inclusion will be automatic if I'm marking it as `virtual` right?

Comment: Yeah, the mechanism calls lazy loading. Lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding virtual properties to add the loading hook

Comment: When I make it `virtual`, still an empty collection is received from the context.
I still do have to explicitly `.Include` what is needed :(